# weasyprint - installation in ubuntu.

Tags: python, weasyprint

I was trying to install weasyprint using command "pip install weasyprint".

It gave me error:

```
requests 2.18.4 has requirement chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2, but you'll have 
chardet 2.3.0 which is incompatible.
tensorboard 1.8.0 has requirement html5lib==0.9999999, but you'll have 
html5lib 1.0.1 which is incompatible.
bleach 1.5.0 has requirement html5lib!=0.9999,!=0.99999, 
<0.99999999,>=0.999, but you'll have html5lib 1.0.1 which is 
incompatible.
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: You should learn to use virtual environments. It'll prevent this kind of things from happening.

Comment: `pip install --upgrade chardet` ... ( `pip install weasyprint` : No issues here, Ubuntu 18.04 ). ... Please edit your question to include Ubuntu version.

Comment: @kund larsen  My ubuntu version is 16.04
The command you gave have fixed two of the errors expcept "weasyprint 0.42.3 has requirement html5lib>=0.999999999, but you'll have html5lib 0.9999999 which is incompatible. " 
any idea how to fix it?